# How to get counts + sum of counts in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table 'workers' which contains data like

```
name    |   category
----------------------
Steve   |   A
Anne    |   B
Linda   |   A
```

... etc

I want to get an overview of categories (counts of categories) PLUS the whole count.

A query of

```
SELECT category, COUNT(category) AS number_of_people
FROM workers
GROUP BY category
```

gets me this far:

```
category    |   number_of_people
----------------------------------
A   |   2
B   |   1
```

But my desired output would be something like:

```
category    |   number_of_people
----------------------------------
A   |   2
B   |   1
-----------------------------------
TOTAL   |   3
```

I'm using MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union

```
SELECT category, COUNT(category) AS number_of_people
FROM workers
GROUP BY category
union
SELECT 'total', COUNT(category) AS number_of_people
FROM workers
```

Comment: Should it not be `SUM(category)` in the union part?

Comment: @B001ᛦ, category is a varchar field

Comment: Ohhh my bad ... I mean SUM(number_of_people) as they are expecting "3" as total

Comment: Works superbly! Thank you very much!